# How to set a custom url for Python interpreter source in Dockerfile?

Tags: python, dockerfile

My Dockerfile starts with:

```
FROM python:3.10.8
```

Source is official site.

How can I set a custom url to interpreter source? I need to specify the path to the tgz-archive with Python in my repository manager.

I looked a documentation in https://hub.docker.com/_/python but I did not find the necessary information there. Google didn`t help me either.

Comment: Use another base for your dockerfile, and then just copy your archive and install it

Comment: Why use `python:3.10.8` if you want to use a different interpeter?

Comment: This is an example of what the dockerfile looks like now. The question is, can I somehow specify another path to the python source instead of "python:3.10.8".

Comment: Is there an easy way to do this by just giving the url in the dockerfile?